# Are double definitions allowed in JSON, and if so, how should they be interpreted?

Tags: json, semantics, definition

Is this valid JSON?

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "name": "bar"
}
```

If so, how should it be interpreted?

Comment: yes this is valid json in terms of syntx. but invalid as both key cant have same name `TIP:` use http://www.jsonlint.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's technically legal, but strongly discouraged, according to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.2):

> The names within an object [SHOULD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119#section-3) be unique.

You can go one of two routes:

- The JavaScript route: In JavaScript, this is illegal. Since JSON is supposed to be a subset, reject the input as invalid.
- The [Postel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)/Python route: Overwrite the `"var"` entry with the latest value.

Comment: @Prisoner Clarified. If it were illegal, the wording would be MUST. Added a link to the formal definition of SHOULD.

Comment: @phihag Thanks for the nice answer and the two alternative ways to process this kind of situations!

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), duplicate names are discouraged. See section **2.2.  Objects**:

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

The above URL also refers us to [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt), which specifies how the word *SHOULD* is interpreted:

> **SHOULD**
>
> This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
>   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>   carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

**However**, many parsers & JSON APIs implement this as *SHOULD ALWAYS*, and throw an error or ignore multiple values upon encountering duplicate properties. This [includes jQuery.parseJSON()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929873/json-parse-multiple-key) as well as [.NET's JSON serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx).

Comment: *SHOULD* doesn't mean that they aren't allowed; it means that they are allowed but discouraged.

Comment: @ Stuart, thanks for the heads up; I have edited my answer to include the formal interpretation according to RFC 2119.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** valid JSON as there are two name variables. Take a read of [this](http://www.json.org/js.html) to help you understand JSON a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

JSon object, like any other object, can not have two attribute with same name. That's illegal in the same way as having same key twice in a map.

JSONObject would throw an exception if you have two keys with same name in one object. You may want to alter your object so that keys are not repeated under same object.

In this case the change would be to make your json key name have value as an array

Answer (score 0):

No, is not. You have two attributes with the same label/name/title. Here is a very [simple and short explanation of the JSON](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29)